# Parse a Javascript String which contains XML

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have this String :

```
var str = "
<tag>
<visibility>visibility</visibility>
<value>value1</value>
<name>TAG1</name>
</tag>

<tag>
<visibility>visibility</visibility>
<value>value2</value>
<name>TAG2</name>
</tag>

<tag>
<visibility>visibility</visibility>
<value>value3</value>
<name>TAG3</name>
</tag>

<tag>
<value>1408709686</value>
<name>TAG4</name>
</tag>
"
```

I would like to get the value of `<value>` tag containing in `<tag>` where `<name>`=TAG2.
So for my example, I would like to get this result :

```
var result = value2 ;
```

How can I parse this? (because `str` contains multiple `<tag>`)

Comment: This XML is invalid, since it contains multiple `tag` elements. No parser will be happy with that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)
api to parse xml strings.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json) can help you out. It explains how to do this by using a custom made function. It turns the XML into JSON you can easily read.

```
// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

You can use this as following:

```
var jsonStr = xmlToJson(str);
alert(jsonStr.tag.value);
```

Comment: Doubly confused here. First, the `xmlToJson` function appears to take an XML object as its argument, not a string. Second, why bother to convert XML to JSON (sic) when you can just access it directly after parsing using the XML DOM or xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, an XML document needs to have a root element, and as you mention your string contains multiple `<tag>` elements.

Simple solution: surround the string with some root element:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString("<root>"+tags+"</root>", "application/xml")
```

(Or use the XML parser of your choice.)